# How to hide a button programmatically?

Tags: android

I have a `RelativeLayout` which contains two buttons. Which are overlapped on each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">


<Button android:text="Play"  
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true">
</Button>

<Button android:text="Stop "
    android:id="@+id/stop" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true">
</Button>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to programmatically show only one button at a time when its click event is called.

I tried it with :

```
playButton.setVisibility(1);
```

but it does not worked. Following is an example what I am trying to do.

```
playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
playButton.setVisibility(1);
playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //when play is clicked show stop button and hide play button

    }
});
```

Answer (score 346, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //when play is clicked show stop button and hide play button
        playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks sunil :) can you please tell the difference between View.VISIBLe and 1  ( is it just enum ) ?

Comment: Why setVisibility to 1? That's not any of the constant values.

Comment: View.GONE makes the item not take up any layout space. View.INVISIBLE  reserves space for the item. This changes the layout of view when you toggle visibility.

Answer (score 88):

Try the below code -

```
playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

or -

```
playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

show it again with -

```
playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 11):

In Kotlin

myButton.visibility = View.GONE

Answer (score 9):

Hidde:

```
BUTTON.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Show:

```
BUTTON.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 8):

Please used below

```
View.GONE and View.VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public void OnClick(View.v)
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
b1.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you only use one button an change the text and the behavior on the button on demand. That's easier and cleaner than handling two buttons which are overlapping.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String curText = ((TextView)v).getText();                 

    if(curText.equals("Play")){
        ((TextView)v).setText("Stop");
    }

    if(curText.equals("Stop")){
        ((TextView)v).setText("Play");
    }
 }
```

Comment: i like your idea its actually what i do in iphone toggling single button to do multiple things.But i am new to android , can you please point me to an example on how to do this..

Answer (score 4):

```
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        //set to visible
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //set to invisble      
        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       //or
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Java**

first connect button or any view you want to make it invisible or visible

```
btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

then first make it visible as below

```
btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I am using onClickListener to show or hide so when the button is clicked
one button will be hidden and second will be shown

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //when button is clicked this button will be hidden
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //  OR 
        btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // here the second button will be show as below
        btn11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

**Kotlin**

```
//For Making Button hide
btn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

//For showing Button
btn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [`View.INVISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE).

Answer (score 3):

Please try this: `playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` I think this will do it.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin code is a lot simpler:

```
if(clearButton.isVisible) {
    clearButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
} else {
    clearButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

**Fun fact:**

`Setting isVisible property to true sets the visibility to View.VISIBLE, false to View.GONE.`

```
view.isVisible = true is equal to view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
view.isVisible = false is equal to view.visibility = View.GONE
```

Answer (score 1):

For "Xamarin Android":

```
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button1).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
```