# Modify a view inside onClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

i have implemented onClickListener and the main activity of my app in a separate classes. The main classes contains some buttons and some edittext, and when the user press a cancel button, the edittext hint should be reset.
main activity

```
public ButtonListener(Context cx , Button b, EditText f) {
    cntx = cx;
    button = b;
    et = f;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //check wich button was pressed
    if(button.getId() == R.button.button_cancel) {
        et.setHint(R.string.et_nome);
    }
    else {
            //operations for other buttons
```

But it doesn't work. When i press cancel, the edittext it's not erased.
In the main activity i've call the button with

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.button.button_cancel);
```

and set the listener

```
b.setOnclickListener(new ButtonListener(this, b, edittext));
```

what's wrong?

Comment: `setHint()` doesn't erase the text, it sets the hint to show *when the view is empty*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the text of it blank:

`et.setText(" ");`

You can view other methods [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

Another way you handle this is by hiding the button to eliminate it temporarily. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173400/how-to-programmatically-hide-a-button-in-android-sdk).

Comment: yes, it works. Could you explain me why i couldn't do with setHint()?

Comment: setHint() is a a permanent element when the view is loaded which is cleared by the user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
if(button.getId() == R.button.button_cancel)
```

to:

```
if(v.getId() == R.button.button_cancel)
```

so that the code checks the identifier of the element that raised the click event, not your member variable `button`.

Comment: this shoub not be a problem, because i've cheched with a log message that the if statement it's called correctly

Comment: Well, it works but it's somewhat redundant. Consider instantiation of another `ButtonListener` class with a `Button` other than `R.button.button_cancel`. Now the if statement of that call will never be true.