# How to customize dashboard view according to user settings

Tags: android, view, settings, customization, dashboard

I'm creating a dashboard but its little different. In my dashboard there would be 6 
buttons views as default. And i will have one setting page with check lists of these all buttons.

Problem is dashboard views should be according to users preference settings.User will select the items in setting page ,those he wants to be visible in dashboard. Unchecked items should not be visible in dashboard.

Please help and thanks in advance.!

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is not a straightforward solution and nobody is going to write code for you...

Answer (score 0):

```
    playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    playButton.setVisibility(1);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
             //when play is clicked show stop button and hide play button
             playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

This solution is taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173400/how-to-programmatically-hide-a-button-in-android-sdk). For more details go to this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).
In setting take input from user and apply accordingly.

Comment: Thakyou @Dev its good way to hide dynamically views. but how to control this from another activity. Because i have to set check in settings activity but view should be change in dashboard. Can you give some example.

Comment: @Mukesh This is not the good solution but I think this will work. Create the static array and fill store the input given by user in this array. As soon as user return back on the dashboard check the variables value and set visibility accordingly. Like this "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosePictureButton).setVisibility(View.GONE); if user does not want to see this button or similar thing."

Comment: I got idea . I can make one database to store user inputs and as soon as user opens dashboard we can fetch database value and acoording to that we can customize views. thank you @Dev hope so it will work out.gonna check out.