# hide show button in android conditionally

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm a newbie on android. can you help me with this?
I want to hide or show a button in a layout, but not when it is clicked.
I mean, when the layout appears, the button is showed or hidden, depending on an `if` condition in java.

the xml is:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width1"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_width1"
    android:id = "@+id/button1"

    android:background="@drawable/facebook"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/space_1"
    android:onClick="browser1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
/>
```

and in my DetailActivity.java I have a function

```
public void browser1(View view) {
    Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.twitter.com"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

can someone help with this?
Regards!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, but maybe this can help: `button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide a button programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173400/how-to-hide-a-button-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

@A.Omar First you have to define a button in your layout xml file like this

```
<Button
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="Test Button"
         android:id="@+id/testButtonId"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

then in your activity class, in the onCreate method get your button pragmatically and set the visibility of button when the button layout appears. like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

    Button testButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.testButtonId);
            if (testButton.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                testButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {
                  testButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

}
```

**Note** make sure you don'y have two onCreate method, othervise you will get the error onCreate method is already define.

Comment: what happend if the code have a onCreated metod pre definided. ?

Comment: You will get an error onCreate Method is already define in your activity

Comment: this works fine,  but in the conditional "if"  i need to hide the button if a one textView button is empty. can you helpme to do the conditional?

Comment: Nicolas i did not understand your problem can explain more?

Comment: you can do some thing like that  if(testButton.getText().equals("")){
testButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the ID assigned to the button in XML, to find it in your Java code, then you can show/hide it.

The code will look like this:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

So your onCreate() code in an Activity would look like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    if(shouldShowButton()) {
        myButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error:(649, 17) error: method onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in class DetailActivity. what sould i do?

Comment: this works fine,  but in the conditional "if"  i need to hide the button if a one textView button is empty. can you helpme to do the conditional?. Regards!

Comment: onCreate() is already defined.. No two onCreate() methods in a class