# Instantiate button on button click in android studio

Tags: android-studio-2.3

I have button on my layout in android studio, thing which i want to know is is it possible when i click on that button and it will instantiate a button right below the button which is clicked. If possible then how it can be achieved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173400/how-to-hide-a-button-programmatically

Comment: Dear @stark sir, it for two buttons but what if have multiple buttons like 100 or maybe more than that, i have to instantiate through web services