# How to make buttons visible with button?

Tags: java, android, button

I want to know how to make some of the buttons appear or visible while clicking other buttons. Like when you add two inputs with 'plus' button, I want buttons to appear instead of summing up.

I don't really have a lot of experience with android studio, but I have tried to search what can help me, however, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a button programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173400/how-to-hide-a-button-programmatically)

Comment: "I want buttons to appear instead of summing up.", What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
Button button1;
Button button2;



        //set a onClickListener on button1 
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (button2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

});
```