# Hide button for In-app Review after a successful review in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I followed this guide to create an in-app review button for my android application in android studio (https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review) everything works correctly, the button is displayed and you can review it.

The issue is that after having successfully completed the review the button is still displayed without any sense, what I want is that if and when the user has placed a review the button simply disappears, but while it does not continue to be displayed, could you help me please.

```
    void startReviewFlow()
{
    if(reviewInfo !=null)
    {
        Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(this,reviewInfo);
        flow.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

            Toast.makeText(this, "¡Gracias, review completada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can hide the button programmatically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173400/how-to-hide-a-button-programmatically

Comment: Please attach your code in your post, so I can help you

Comment: i add my code @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI

Comment: I think you need to add if(task.isSuccessful),  try this : https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java#request-review-info